# Poweshell script remove footer function taking too long

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This PowerShell is taking a long time to remove the footer. The file is around 300 MB. Below is the code I've written. The first step copies the file and then unzips it. Then the requirement is to remove the footer. As the file is huge it takes a long while to remove it. I'm running this locally in PowerShell.

## Function to unzip files

```
function Unzip-Files {
    param (
        [string]$Source,
        [string]$Destination
    )
    try {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($Source, $Destination)
        Write-Host "Successfully unzipped file '$Source' to '$Destination'"
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to unzip file '$Source' to '$Destination': $_"
    }
}

# Function to remove footer record from files
function Remove-Footer {
    param (
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    try {
        $lines = Get-Content $FilePath
        $linesWithoutFooter = $lines[0..($lines.Count - 2)]
        Set-Content -Path $FilePath -Value $linesWithoutFooter
        Write-Host "Successfully removed footer from '$FilePath'"
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to remove footer from '$FilePath': $_"
    }
}

# Variables
$sourceLocation = "nas:\location1"
$destinationLocation = "nas:\location2"

try {
    # Step 1: Copy files from nas location1 to nas location2
    Write-Host "Copying files from '$sourceLocation' to '$destinationLocation'"
    Copy-Item -Path $sourceLocation\* -Destination $destinationLocation -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "Files copied successfully"

    # Iterate through each file in the destination location
    Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationLocation -File -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_

        # Step 2: Unzip the files
        if ($file.Extension -eq ".zip") {
            $unzippedFolder = Join-Path $destinationLocation $file.BaseName

            if (Test-Path $unzippedFolder) {
                Write-Error "Failed to unzip file '$file.FullName' because the destination folder '$unzippedFolder' already exists."
                continue
            }

            Unzip-Files -Source $file.FullName -Destination $unzippedFolder

            # Step 3: Remove the footer record from unzipped files
            Get-ChildItem -Path $unzippedFolder -File | ForEach-Object {
                Remove-Footer -FilePath $_.FullName
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error "An error occurred during the script execution: $_"
}
```

Is there an efficient way to remove footer of the file? Please help me if I'm doing this in the right way.

Should I rewrite this in a shell script? does that help?

Comment: Is the file encoding known in advance? And / or an estimate of the length of the footer (e.g. less than 1024 characters?, less than 1,024,000 characters?). It *might* be possible to work *backwards* from the end of the file using ```System.IO.FileStream``` to look for the last line-break (```\r\n``` or ```\n```) and then truncate the file at that position with ```FileStream.SetLength```, but it depends on being able to jump into the file without reading the first few "encoding marker" bytes, or landing part way through a multi-byte encoded character...

Answer (score 1):

Your `Remove-Footer` function can be simplified as follows to make it more efficient while not recurring to `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` and also leverage pipeline processing:

```bash
function Remove-Footer {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string] $Path
    )

    process {
        try {
            [System.Linq.Enumerable]::SkipLast(
                [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($Path), 2) |
                Set-Content ($tmp = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName())

            Move-Item $tmp -Destination $Path -Force

            Write-Host "Successfully removed footer from '$Path'"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to remove footer from '$Path': $_"
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is no need for a `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $unzippedFolder -File | Remove-Footer
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a more efficient way to remove the footer from large files. Instead of reading the entire file into memory using Get-Content, you can use a combination of StreamReader and StreamWriter to read and write the file line by line. This approach will significantly reduce memory usage and improve performance.

Here's the updated Remove-Footer function using StreamReader and StreamWriter:

```
    # Function to remove footer record from files
function Remove-Footer {
    param (
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    try {
        $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
        $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($FilePath)
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $tempFile

        while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
            if ($reader.Peek() -ne -1) {
                $writer.WriteLine($line)
            }
        }
        $reader.Close()
        $writer.Close()
        Move-Item -Path $tempFile -Destination $FilePath -Force
        Write-Host "Successfully removed footer from '$FilePath'"
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Failed to remove footer from '$FilePath': $_"
    }
}
```

Comment: disposal of the streams should be done in the `finally` block not in the `try` block